# Plot two images side by side with skimage

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, plot, scikit-image

Looking up at different feature matching tutorials I've noticed that it's tipical to illustrate how the matching works by plotting side by side the same image in two different version (one normal and the other one rotated or distorted). I want to work on feature matching by using two distinct images (same scene shot from slightly different angles). How do I plot them together side by side? 
I'm willing to use skimage on python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `skimage.feature.plot_matches`, pass empty list of keypoints and matches if you only want to plot the images without points.

Comment: Hi! thank you, I'll try with plot_matches. Is it possible to use as keypoints the blobs extracted with a blob detector (this is exactly my task)?

Comment: Yes, just use the first two columns of the return value of the blob functions. You may have to reverse the order of the two columns, due to differe XY vs. YX convention.